# Failed to decode data coming from client

Tags: swift, alamofire, vapor

I am following Ray Wanderlich's book 'Server Side Swift with Vapor' and I am at chapter 26: Adding profile pictures.

First, I defined this struct:

```
struct ImageUploadData: Content {
    var picture: Data
}
```

Then, in a route I try to decode it:

```
func postProfilePictureHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<User> {
    let data = try req.content.decode(ImageUploadData.self)
    ...
```

From the client side, I use Alamofire:

```
@discardableResult func uploadProfilePicture(for user: User, data: Data) async throws -> User {
    enum Error: LocalizedError {
        case missingUserID
    }
    
    guard let userID = user.id else {
        throw Error.missingUserID
    }
    
    let appendix = "\(userID)/profilePicture"
    let parameters = [
        "picture": data
    ]
    
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        Task {
            AF.request(baseUrl + appendix, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseData { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    do {
                        let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                        continuation.resume(returning: user)
                    } catch {
                        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my integration tests, I create the picture's data like this:

```
guard let data = image?.pngData() else {
    throw Error.missingPictureData
}
```

And then I pass it to the above method. The problem is that in the server side, the decoding fails with this error:

> The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

Just to understand if I was doing something else wrong, I tried the above methods with one difference: I replace the type 'Data' with 'String':

```
struct ImageUploadData: Content {
    var picture: String
}
```

This wouldn't be useful for me because I need a data object, but just as a test to see if this doesn't produce an error, I tried and indeed this is decoded successfully. So I suspect that the problem is in how I encode the data before sending it to the server, but I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: The decoding error message tells me you are printing the error incorrectly using localizedDescription. Just use `print(error)` to get a more informative error message

Comment: What is the point of the `Task` inside the `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` block? probably not relevant to the issue but something to look into.

Comment: Like lorem ipsum said, there's no point to the continuation. Alamofire already provides an async API you should use instead: `serializingDecodable`.